# How do I add/remove tables to a Windows Azure database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a Windows Azure database which I wish to add/remove tables to, and yesterday I witnessed a colleague do this online, on what looked like a web based SQL management studio, but I can't find it anywhere.

I can see a **Manage** button in the toolbar at the bottom of the page, but all this seems to do is refresh the page. How do I reach the web based management console I saw my colleague use yesterday?

I also tried to connect to the database using Visual Studio's server explorer, but when I try to add a table, I get this helpful error:

[image: Error]

Comment: How about asking your colleague?  (Well, I see it's weekend just now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Manage button is correct. It should bring up a page in a new window/tab that prompts for the user name and password to connect to the database. If that isn't working, there's something wrong with your web browser configuration (does it allow popups from the Azure site?).

Alternatively, the database *server* can be set up to allow external connections by managing the firewall rules. The interface makes it very easy to poke a hole just for your client computer. You can then connect to the database directly using Management Studio on your local machine. (Don't forget to delete the firewall rule when you're finished.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the format of your managment portal.

Substitute the yoursqlservername (usually something like bhjjeliwwk :)

```
https://yoursqlservername.database.windows.net
```

It's the same as in your connection string.